# Check constraint issue with SQL Server and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, check-constraints

I have a strange issue. From my application I am calling two stored procedures to insert into two different tables. The second insert is based on the insert through first stored procedure.

Right now what is happening is the second stored procedure is throwing check constraint errors.

My second stored procedure is for inserting into a table which do have a user defined function as check constraint.

While debugging I found a strange behavior. If I execute the stored procedure directly from SSMS before it get executed from the application (I put a breakpoint to delay the execution of stored procedure), insert is working fine. And the function used for check constraint is giving correct value.

After that I continued from breakpoint and stored procedure execution is throwing check constraint failed error.

Has anyone else faced a similar behaviour?

Comment: Are you using async?

Comment: no. i am calling both from same controller action. no async is used

Comment: Please refer https://www.codemag.com/article/0305111/Handling-SQL-Server-Errors-in-Nested-Procedures

Comment: Is there a dependent value from the first executed sp that you use on your second sp?